# Perl reading XLSX embeded documents

Tags: linux, perl, xlsx

First post here so if I am doing something stupid, please let me know.

CentOS 7(3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64), perl5 (revision 5 version 16 subversion 3), Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX v0.16

I have an .xlsx that has some embedded .pdf's and another xlsx in embedded within it.  I am trying to read these and insert them into a csv along with the original xlsx.   After some googl'ing to no avail my thought was to unzip the original xlsx and read the files from the xl/embeddings directory but, alas there is something with the file that causes adobe reader to not be able to read the oleObject(X).bin files in that dir. 
I have been able to successfully read all the worksheets that dio not contain embedded docs using Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX, works great. I have googled for a solution but am either not using correct search prams or ...
If you know how to do this can you point me to some instructions?

TIA,
JohnM